# Low-side switch TPL7407LA-Q1

Tags: switches, datasheet, low-side

I have some questions regarding the [TPL7407LA-Q1](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpl7407la-q1.pdf?ts=1681537150931&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Fpower-switches%252Flow-side-switches%252Fproducts.html) low-side switch.

As far as I know, this IC is typically coupled with GPIO pins on a microcontroller, so supply voltages are limited. On the product page, it does say "input compatibility CMOS/TTL".

Is this somehow related to the CMOS used within? What is the purpose of the CMOS as seen in the block diagram (is it some sort of active-low enable)?

a. When the input is high (i.e >=V<sub>IH</sub>) then the output is V<sub>OL</sub>. This makes complete sense for CMOS logic, but how is the load driven with output low?

b. There is mention of sink current: "Applications requiring sink currents beyond
the capability of a single output may be accommodated by paralleling the outputs."
[image]
I just don't get why the current is said to be flowing into the pin, **even for the output pins**. How does it make sense in order to drive some load? Shouldn't the current be sourced out of the output? And why is there emphasis on sink currents throughout?

[image]

2. **(Solved)** "7 channels", does this mean 7 of the circuits shown below for each corresponding input-output pair?

[image]

3. **(Solved)** Since I haven't really understood the channels term yet, so I need clarification on the below plot as well.
   [image]

Does each NMOS Control ckt (labelled as N = 1, 2 ,3 .. 7) have different characteristics OR are they comparing if they're was a single channel IC vs dual .. and so on?

4. [image]
   **(Solved)** Need help with the terms V<sub>OK</sub> and I<sub>OK</sub> These values haven't been mentioned anywhere in the datasheet. What do these signify? Like apart from the name, could you help me understand it with a use case?

---

Going through the terms open collector / open drain has allowed me to understand the IC functionality better. Kindly help me know if my derived conclusions are right.

This IC inherently only supports Pull down functionality(i.e., Bringing the output to LOW state aka GND). {can provide Pull up with an external pull up resistor i.e. Output HIGH}.

*The CMOS inverter AKA NOT gate in the Pin Package essentially describes its behaviour and not actually present.*  (is this correct to say?)

If the V<sub>IN</sub> > V<sub>IH</sub> then NMOS is turned ON, thereby completing the path to the GND. Pull DOWN.

If V<sub>IN</sub> < V<sub>IL</sub> then NMOS is turned OFF, thereby the output is left floating. If there's an external pull up resistor (connected between V<sub>DD</sub> and before load as seen below the load is driven high.

But the lower potential will still be at the OUTPUT pin. **Where does the current EXIT?**

[image]

Comment: Your question title is not specifying what is your problem; merely naming a component in the question title would not help others with same or similar issues more easily come across it. You also have MANY questions wrapped inside one, instead of focusing on one or two main issues. The EESE is specific questions, specific issues/problems, asking for specific solutions. It is not for broad, vague and multiple questions requiring a whole "class session", so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is an open-collector, and based on the logic once VINx >= VIH, you will have VOL.

[image]

2. Yes!
3. They all work the same way, what this graph means is that the more pair of input-outputs you use, the lower maximum current is.
4. If you check the capture of the circuit of each channel, there is a clamp diode. The VOK is the absolute maximum reverse voltage it supports, and IOK the maximum clamp current. If you are not using inductive loads, you probably don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Okay so for this particular load switch IC. For (3) I'd only have to see N = 7 curve and not the others.

I did not understand the term 'open collector' 

Also about the output being V(OL) how does it drive the load connected ahead? How is output sink current used / is useful as it has been mentioned quite  a lot in the datasheet.

Comment: In this case, it is open-drain. You may be used to push-pull outputs, where the High and Low states are available in the output. In an open-drain like this, just the low state will be available, or the output will be open.  There is a similar IC, that many people like using called ULN2003 (it may help you to understand how to use it).

Comment: Okay, so only when the input is HIGH i.e. V(IH) then the enhancement type NMOS is ON. Which then produces some current listed as I(DS) (maximum drain current), which can be 0 - 500 mA (as per datasheet). This is the amount of current that can be seen at the Output terminals of the IC & the corresponding voltage is V(OL).  Now as loads will have a separate supply say (12 V) the current flows from the external supply for load into the output pins. Is this conclusion right? AFAIK Low side switches can be implemented with either Darlington pairs(NPN) or NMOS(en).

Comment: Make sure ground in shared between the different power supplies in this case. And if you want to work with currents close to 500mA you may want consider the power dissipation.

Comment: Thanks for your help up until now; however, I don't understand what is happening at the output. There is no substantial voltage at the output or substantial current. I guess I'm trying to misinterpret it as a Driver while it's just a switch. I'll review the Darlington array implementation for clarity in my thought process. Also the clamp diode you mentioned is it the same one as seen in between COM & OUT pin ?

Comment: Yes it is that diode!

Comment: "It is an open-collector, and based on the logic once VINx >= VIH, you will have VOH." Shouldnt this be "It is an open-collector, and based on the logic once VINx >= VIH, you will have **VOL**."

Comment: Yes you are right  as it is in the capture! Thanks, edited

Comment: Hey,  I tried to develop an understanding based on your answers. If you could review my conclusions it'd be of great help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145364/discussion-between-mf3-and-harkirat).